# prettyprinter: Linebreak on narrow margin, mempty otherwise

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm using the [`prettyprinter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter) library to prettyprint `foo(bar, baz)`, and when the margin is too narrow, I'd like it to look like:

```
foo(
  bar,
  baz)
```

How do I do that?

My best attempts so far:

```
> import Prettyprinter
> import Prettyprinter.Util
> let commas = punctuate comma

-- 'sep' and 'nest' seem to go well together, but the result lacks the linebreak
> putDocW 10 ("foo" <> parens (nest 2 (sep (commas ["bar", "baz"]))))
foo(bar,
  baz)

-- Using 'line'' inside 'nest' almost does the trick
> putDocW 10 ("foo" <> parens (nest 2 (line' <> sep (commas ["bar", "baz"]))))
foo(
  bar,
  baz)

-- Except 'line'' doesn't seem "mempty" enough
> putDocW 20 ("foo" <> parens (nest 2 (line' <> sep (commas ["bar", "baz"]))))
foo(
  bar, baz)
```

I thought what I want is [`line'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.7.0/docs/Prettyprinter.html#v:line-39-) because of the mention of `mempty`:

> `line'` is like `line`, but behaves like `mempty` if the line break is undone by `group` (instead of `space`).

But perhaps I misunderstand what "undone by `group`" does.

It seems that none of the other ones (`line`, `softline` and `softline'`) give better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not confident this is the “right” way, but here’s a way:

```
hcat
  [ "prefix"
  , nest 2 $ cat
    $ "("
    : punctuate (flatAlt "," ", ")
      [ "first"
      , "second"
      , "third"
      ]
  , ")"
  ]
```

That is, hang the concatenation of the opening parenthesis and punctuated elements after the prefix, separating them with or without trailing space depending on whether they’re folded, and tack on the closing parenthesis.

Alternatively, you could make your own variant of `encloseSep` that adds separators at the end rather than the beginning, and includes the opening delimiter in the `cat`:

```
encloseSepEnd
  :: Doc ann -> Doc ann -> Doc ann -> [Doc ann] -> Doc ann
encloseSepEnd open close sep docs = case docs of
  [] -> open <> close
  [doc] -> open <> doc <> close
  _ -> cat (open : suffixReverse (close : repeat sep) docs)

suffixReverse
  :: (Foldable t, Semigroup a)
  => [a] -> t a -> [a]
suffixReverse separators
  = snd . foldr go (separators, [])
  where
    go doc (sep : seps, acc) = (seps, doc <> sep : acc)
```

```
hcat
  [ "prefix"
  , nest 2 $ encloseSepEnd "(" ")" ", "
    ["first", "second", "third"]
  ]
```

Aside, honestly I find that I invariably have to replace bracketing functions like `parens` with their separate parts in order to achieve the results I want, and `group` never behaves how I wish it did.